# PyAlgo Trade failed to read a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pyalgotrade

i tried to code below:

```
from pyalgotrade.feed import csvfeed

feed=csvfeed.Feed("Date","%Y.%M.%d %H:%m:%S")

feed.addValuesFromCSV('/Users/emacsen/Duka_Data/EURUSD_UTC_1 Min_Bid_2005.01.01_2015.10.05.csv')
```

and an error turned out to be :

> dateTime =
>   datetime.datetime.strptime(csvRowDict[self.__dateTimeColumn],
>   self.__dateTimeFormat) KeyError: 'Date'

if I use formatting style "Date","%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S" ,same error:

```
feed=csvfeed.Feed("Date","%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

feed.addValuesFromCSV('/Users/emacsen/Duka_Data/EURUSD_UTC_1 Min_Bid_2005.01.01_2015.10.05.csv')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/Users/emacsen/anaconda/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/feed/csvfeed.py", line 171, in addValuesFromCSV
>     return BaseFeed.addValuesFromCSV(self, path)
>
> File "/Users/emacsen/anaconda/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/feed/csvfeed.py", line 90, in addValuesFromCSV
>       dateTime, rowValues = self.__rowParser.parseRow(row)
>
> File "/Users/emacsen/anaconda/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyalgotrade/feed/csvfeed.py", line 108, in parseRow
>       dateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(csvRowDict[self.__dateTimeColumn], self.__dateTimeFormat)
>   KeyError: 'Date'

---

if I use pandas.read_csv() instead,it can be well read ,  so what is wrong with my Date formatting?

the csv file is formatted

```
Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume 

2005.01.02 22:00:00,1.35464,1.3548,1.35464,1.3548,152.2
2005.01.02 22:01:00,1.35485,1.35489,1.35464,1.35479,409.1
2005.01.02 22:02:00,1.35492,1.35492,1.3547,1.3547,687.5
2005.01.02 22:03:00,1.35493,1.35501,1.35469,1.35486,604
2005.01.02 22:04:00,1.35485,1.35507,1.35478,1.3548,541.5
```

the last column is traded volume of EUR/USD

and by the way, how does pyalgotrade go along with pandas? can i use pandas to read a csv file and transfer that to pyalgotrade?

Comment: Shouldn't the format be `("Date","%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")` e.g. month and minute formats swapped around

Comment: Also how do you determine the column header names? your sample includes no header line

Comment: Don't post as comment, edit your question so we don't lose formatting, also did you try my format string?

Comment: Your csv shows no column called `Date` you do have one called `Time`

Comment: Have you tried on 'Time' column? `"Time","%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: yes that is right, it is working now. and .....but pyalgotrade is rather slow to read a large csv file more than 4 million lines .can i read it into pandas and transfer it to pyalgotrade?

Comment: @user2834945 If you have a new question, I encourage you to submit that as a new question on StackOverflow, that will have the best chance of getting you a quality answer.

Comment: I have no idea about pyalgotrade, unless it supports numpy arrays as dtype then no is the answer, otherwise I can post why your original error occurred and you can accept my answer so this question remains closed

Comment: As-is, I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because it was caused by typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple errors, the `KeyError` is because you tried to refer to a column that didn't exist, it's `Time` and not `Date`, the second is your format string, your month and minute specifier should be swapped around:

```
feed=csvfeed.Feed("Time","%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
```

is the correct form, see the docs: http://strftime.org/

As to the slow performance and compatibility with pandas I have no idea, pyalgotrade needs to support `numpy` arrays in order for it to work with a pandas df.